# ViewExpiredException for JSF/Primefaces Ajax Request after Spring RememberMe Authentification

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with Primefaces and client side view state

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When trying to restore the view of an AJAX request, I get a ViewExpiredException.
This currently only occurs when an authentification via Spring RememberMe has been performed and only applies to the AJAX Request and not, if the page is completely reloaded.

Some Analysis:

The system tries to restore the view in

```
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doGetState(String stateString)
```

which then calls

```
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.decrypt(byte[] bytes)
```

Here the method

```
 Arrays.equals(macBytes, macBytesCalculated)
```

fails and the error

```
ERROR: MAC did not verify!
```

is triggered, which prevents the view from being restored.
I guess that it has to do with different encryption logic between the given content of the AJAX Request and the decryption in ByteArrayGuard.

I also tested the latest version of as provided in https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2553 however, it did not change the behaviour. (in opposite to      JAVASERVERFACES-2553 my problem is not related to thread safety...)

Any ideas?

Thanks and kind regards, Chris

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR: MAC did not verify!
Nov 29, 2013 2:58:15 AM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/page.xhtml - Ansicht /pages.xhtml konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden.
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my thoughts were correct, the problem can be solved by patching method setupKeyAndMac() in com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard und thus preventing from generating a new random secret on server startup:

```
private void setupKeyAndMac() {

try {
    // caution, use exact this length!
    String secret = "1256325896545822129522";
    sk = new SecretKeySpec(new Base64().decode(secret.getBytes()), "AES");
    // KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
    // kg.init(KEY_LENGTH); // 256 if you're using the Unlimited Policy Files
    // sk = kg.generateKey();

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new FacesException(e);
}
}
```

see http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/shared/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/shared/util/StateUtils.java for an implementation reference with the possibility to configure a static MAC secret in web.xml.

Answer (score -2):

use below code

use **PROJECT_STAGE** instead of **STATE_SAVING_METHOD** and use param value as **Development**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, could you shortly explain why PROJECT_STAGE=Development should solve the problem? I did some research and it looks like the problem is caused as the system generates a new random secret on startup. I use Mojarra, which offers no possibility to define a static secret like myfaces does (org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET). Right know, I am trying to patch com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard in order always use the same secret key.